# Potentially malicious software: was it removed?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

I downloaded what may have been a malicious extension on Google Chrome. I don't know if that was a legitimate extension or not; I got it in order to access Pearson, hand-typing a link that another student (with no motive to prank me) showed me (am I a victim of [typosquatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting)?). I was able to remove it from Chrome, which is a step above what I've seen another similar malicious extension do on another computer. **How do I know if it is really gone?**

If I am the victim of something malicious, **is there any way that this could have compromised my Google account?** I have that intertwined with a lot of things, including my university account. If so, **what should I do?** Is there any information that I have to go off of to justify buying a new computer?

The name of the extension was "Safe Search." The publisher is "Safely." It wasn't "Search Safely Search."

Comment: Are you sure it isn't Search Safely Search? Did you happen to see where the Home page went to?

Comment: The home page was almost my normal homepage, but not quite. I did not pay enough attention as to what it was.

Comment: By the way, I've downloaded Malwarebytes and it said it found nothing (on the computer). Is there a possibility that *Chrome*, however, may still have something?

Comment: No virus scan is perfect but you're probably OK. I don't think you had a virus in the first place, just a tracking extension. It's malware but not all malware are viruses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is malware called Search Safely Search that appears to be designed to generate income for it's creators by redirecting searches to Yahoo and track your movements. I would uninstall any new software that appears suspicious and the extension and then run a malware check. If you don't have a anti-malware program my favorite is Malwarebytes. Google Search Safely Search for more info on it.